# Can someone please help me identity this font?

Tags: fonts

[image]

I'm working on a project for a memorial, can someone please let me identify this font?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a higher resolution.

Answer (score 1):

**Silverline Sans Bold** comes close, if I compare the A with the low stroke and the G. But the image is simply too low res to accurately tell. The stroke from the A seems to be even lower than it already is in the Silverline...

Just a tip: under https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ you can upload any image with a snippet of text on it and it compares the font to any font in their catalogue. But keep in mind: the lower the resolution and size of the image, the more inaccurate the results are.

[image: Whatthefont_Gefangenen_ Silverline Sans bold]

Answer (score 0):

The font belongs to **Offlander** font family, it comes in two versions .i.e. *Simple and Rough*[image: Sample Text - Offlander Font]

Offlander (Complete Font Family - Paid): https://creativemarket.com/craftsupplyco/2878218-Offlander-Font-Family?u=beacon9688

 Offlander (Rough Version - Free): https://fontlot.com/61589/offlander-font-family/

Let me search free version for you.

Comment: Just to add-on, may be the font face is not exactly the same because the provided image is in low res and blurry; but still it still seems 90% close to it.

Comment: To be honest at that size it could be any font, but I can tell you that he "A" bar is not the same